# SQL Jobs not being listed with Powershell

Tags: powershell, sql-job

Using the powershell code below, the script runs and nothing happens. There ARE existing Jobs. And the Server name is correct. No error, it just runs and immediately returns.

```
$srv = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server("sql01") 

$srv.JobServer.Jobs | Where-Object {$_.Name -notlike "sys*"} | Select Name
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: what happens if you leave the where-object out?

Comment: Same thing. I have figured it out, see below. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this and it worked:

```
$outnm = ".\" + $svr + "\" + $instnm + "_Jobs.csv"  
$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$SqlCmd.CommandText = "exec msdb.dbo.sp_help_job"
$SqlCmd.Connection = $cn
$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
$SqlConnection.Close()
$DataSet.Tables[0] | Select originating_server, name, description, owner,     last_run_date, enabled | where {$_.Name -notlike 'sys*'} | export-csv -path $outnm -noType
```